# Convert "adjacent nodes table" to a graph

Tags: excel, graph, visio

Given the "adjacent nodes table", is it possible to convert it to a "hierarchy graph" using Microsoft Office products such as [Visio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio) or [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)?

[image: Adjacent nodes table]

[image: Hierarchy graph]

Answer (score 0):

The final structure should be something like: "ID | parentID | item" which you can use to draw automatically the diagram.

The parentID should be fairly easy to obtain, since it is the last but one non empty value in the adjacent tables.

Comment: Can you please add more details? maybe you can share the file that implements the solution. Thanks